# How to mock sling PropertyIterator?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, iterator, jackrabbit, sling

I have following code to test:

```
  static Set<String> methodToTest(Node crxProductNode, OfflineNodeAction nodeAction, Set<String> allowedAttributes) throws RepositoryException {
        Set<String> changedPropertiesKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        final PropertyIterator crxProductNodeProperties = crxProductNode.getProperties();
        while (crxProductNodeProperties.hasNext()) {
            final String crxNodePropertyName = crxProductNodeProperties.nextProperty().getName();
            if(nodeAction.getProperties(crxNodePropertyName)==null && allowedAttributes.contains(crxNodePropertyName)){
                changedPropertiesKeys.add(crxNodePropertyName);
            }
        }
        return changedPropertiesKeys;
    }
```

Please advise me how to test following code.

I have problem with Iterator mocking. I don't understand how to mock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this exists class

```
org.apache.sling.commons.testing.jcr.MockNode
```

and

```
MockNodeIterator
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `PropertyIterator` is received from `crxProductNode` and it is a parameter passed to the method, it is a book definition of so called "test collaborator".

**We should mock out test collaborators, in your case mock the `crxProductNode` to return another mock of type `PropertyIterator`** and pass it to the method.

The concrete code depends on your mocking framework, but should be something like the following pseudo code:

```
@Test
public void testMyPropertyIterator() {
    Sut sut = new SUT(); // System Under Test, the class with your method

    Node nodeMock                   = mock(Node.class);
    PropertyIterator mockProperties = mock(PropertyIterator.class);

    when(nodeMock.getProperties()).thenReturn(mockProperties);

    sut.methodToTest(nodeMock, ...);

   // verification or assertions
}
```

Comment: **nodeMock.getProperties()** returns iterator

Comment: This is handled by mocking: when(nodeMock.getProperties()).thenReturn(mockProperties);
 is syntax from Mockito.

Comment: I understand mockito syntax

Comment: mockProperties should be PropertyIterator mock

Comment: Can you provide unit test entirely for my method? collection underlyed the iterator should contains at least 3 elements